# Set value of file input in React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

How can I set a default value in my `input type="file"` in a React hook form? I have files in my data and when I edit that data I want show my Preview of myfile

```
<TextField type="file" name={`englishProficiency.${index}.uploadTestResult`} variant="outlined" onChange={uploadResult} />
```

I tried to use `defaultValue` here with my console data which is `englishProficiency.0.uploadTestResult: "104.PNG"`

Comment: It's not possible to set the default value in a file control. This is in order to ensure security of the local filesystem. Whatever you're trying to do, you'll need to find another way.

Comment: *"I want show my Preview of myfile"* - If the file is an image, wouldn't you use a `<img>` element to preview it?  The application **displaying** a file from the server and the user **selecting** a file from their computer are two entirely different things, you appear to be trying to mix them.